# How to set the source data of a chart to table content using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I am wondering why this code is not working. I get an error with the very last row when I would like to adjust the data source of the chart to a dynamic table (=ListObject).

Any ideas? Thank you!

```
Sub test()

Dim WSfollowers As Worksheet
Set WSfollowers = ActiveSheet

Dim chartFollowers As ChartObject
Set chartFollowers = WSfollowers.ChartObjects("chart_followers")

Dim TBL As ListObject
Set TBL = WSfollowers.ListObjects("tbl_followers")

chartFollowers.SetSourceData Source:=TBL.Range

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, replace:

```
chartFollowers.SetSourceData Source:=TBL.Range
```

with

```
chartFollowers.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=TBL.Range
```

Only the `Chart` property of a `ChartObject` has a `SetSourceData` property...

Now, according to what you need accomplishing, you can also use `TBL.DataBodyRange`.

Comment: what if the table is a pivot table?